# Attach a jQuery dialog to a text field and make it disappear when the user clicks something else?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-datepicker

I like the jQuery DatePicker widget.  It is very user friendly that when the user clicks on a date field in my web application, the user sees a dialog that allows her to select a date.

What's even better is the way the datepicker is so unobtrusive.  If the user doesn't want to use the datepicker, she can easily type a date on her own.  Furthermore, the datepicker automagically disappears when the user clicks on anything that isn't the datepicker or shifts the focus to another field.

What I would like to do is have the same functionality with the jQuery dialog.  Basically, I want to create a dialog with some widgets that the user can use to select a value for a text field.

I want the dialog to automatically appear underneath the text field when the field is selected.  I want it to automatically disappear after the user shifts the focus somewhere else.

In order to accomplish this, I've attached a handler to the text field `.focus` event in jQuery to make the dialog appear.  That works fine.  :-)

I've tried adding a handler to the `.blur` event to make the dialog automatically close when the user goes somewhere else.  However, merely opening the dialog causes the `blur` event to fire, closing it :-/

Furthermore, I don't know of any way to make the dialog appear directly underneath the text field the same way that the datepicker does.

How can I make a jQuery dialog appear next to a text field and disappear appropriately like the datepicker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**See example of the following here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/cXSJz/1/)

First, to make the dialog appear beneath the input, use `position:absolute` and the jQuery `.offset()` method to find the position of the input in question to assign values to the position of the dialog.  For example:

```
$('#input').focus(function(e){
    var $t = $(this),
        $d = $('#dialog'),
        to = $t.offset();

    $d.css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'top':to.top + $t.height() + 4,
        'left':to.left
      })
      .show();
});
```

In the above, I positioned the dialog by adding the top value of the input to the height of the input plus a 4px buffer.

Second, to hide the dialog, attach a click handler to the document that doesn't hide the dialog if the event target is either the dialog or the input.  Like so:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if (e.target.id !== "dialog" && e.target.id !== "input") {
        $('#dialog').hide();
    }
}
```

[See example.](http://jsfiddle.net/cXSJz/1/)

Comment: It seems like my browser returns `16` for `$('#input').height()`, but `$('#input').left` is undefined, as is `top`.

Comment: `$('#input').offset().left` and `.top`

Answer (score 1):

i can't give a direct answer.
but my first try would be to look up how the DatePicker does the trick with the position [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js?r=3639)

it seems to me, the widget is dynamically generated when needed and not placed there from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use the actual jQuery UI-Dialog features, here's one way:

```
$('#main').find('input').click(function(e) {
    var $box = $('<div class="box" />').html('In dialog'); // make a dialog
    var xpos = $(this).position().left; // get position of clicked field
    var ypos = $(this).position().top + 20;
    $box.dialog({ // trigger the dialog
        position: [xpos, ypos], // position it relative to clicked object
        close: function() { // destroy on close for neatness
            $(this).dialog('destroy');
        }
    }).mouseleave(function() { // if you mouseout:
        $(this).dialog('close'); // close the dialog
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/dAr69/

Comment: How do I make the dialog disappear if the user navigates away from the text field with the [TAB] key?

Comment: You could trigger a `close` on the dialog on the `blur` event... but it sounds like you're inching closer and closer to a tooltip-type requirement.